# Excel 2013 MDX OLAP PivotTable Extension: Not Able to see Calculations tab

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table, excel-2013

I just recently learned about OLAP PivotTable Extensions, and after I installed the add-in, as well as the PowerPivot add-in, I still don't see the option to add Calculations in the OLAP Pivot Table Extensions window.

Is there something I'm missing?

I need this because I found out that after I connected to an Access db that I can no longer create Calculated fields from the pivot table.  The table is too large to store in the Excel file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you connected to a cube?

Access is not olap. Try connecting a vanilla pivot table to an olap cube - does the calculations section now appear?

Comment: Hmm...  Well, I thought maybe Access was included in the list of options either way. Allow me to rephrase the question then:

How would I be able to connect to an Access db table without having to pull in and store all of the data in Excel (again, too many records), and be able to add calculated fields? I'm able to do the first part just fine, but the calcs are essential because I need to have several per case and variance columns. 

SQL server is not an option either at this point. Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: I suppose I could try the Power Pivot option, but the data and queries reside in Access. I'm also concerned about performance and how this would work with other users that don't have Power Pivot.

Comment: @RARascon is it not possible to include some of the calculations in Access? I suppose you're already doing this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-an-Access-database-to-your-workbook-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525

Comment: Yes, but when using the pivot I need the calcs to be dynamic depending on changing filters and slicers.

Comment: So far, I have been able to accomplish the calculated fields through PowerPivot. But again I'm concerned about other users that don't use PowerPivot and if they'll have problems accessing the data in the file that has the pivot table.